# On table row click, alert box shows click value

Tags: javascript, ajax

i'm having problems where when i click the tablerow, nothing is being shown. 
[image]

When I click lets say the row where customername= 'John', the name 'John' should appear on a alert box, but nothing happens.

This is my table click code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#parentElementIdHere").on("click", "#test tr", function(e) {
var name = $(this).find("td").first().text();
alert(name);
});
```

And, here is my generating of table code.

```
if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
$q = $_GET['q'];
$query="select * from customer where customername like '$q%'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$query);
echo "<div id='parentElementIdHere'>";
echo "<table id='test' border=3>
<tr>
<th>Customername</th>
<th>nric</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>mobileno</th>
<th>telephoneno</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>postalcode</th>
<th>datejoined</th>
<th>points</th>
</tr>";
while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['customername'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nric'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mobileno'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['telephoneno'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['occupation'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['postalcode'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['datejoined'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['points'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
} 
echo "</table>"; 
echo "</div>";
}
```

Could the problem be because my table generated is constantly changing because of ajax?

Comment: Yes, dynamically changing the table via ajax is *one* problem. The other problem is that your selector `'#test tr #name'` says to select elements with `id="name"` that are *descendants* of `tr` elements, but it is actually your `tr` elements that all have that id. Not to mention that duplicate ids is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I tested with a non ajax generated sql table and did it. Then i brought over the javascript code over to this file and tried it out. This is the code i used.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
}).on('click','.test tr',function(){
var id = $(this).attr('value');
alert(id);
});
```

Thanks to all who helped me i appreciate it!

Comment: What does the value attribute of a row give O.o  I mean how does it give the name ? Im just curious. :)

Comment: @BlackBurn027 ermmm i echo-ed this out when i was generating the table.  echo "<tr value=". $row['customername'] .">";

Comment: Okie, try not to attach "value" attributes to non input tags of HTML use data-* attributes like <tr data-value="5">, thats a HTML5 feature lets you store data in any HTML attributes thats a good practice which is followed and u can access it in jquery like $('tr').data('value');

Answer (score 2):

To get name value for click on any value of the row

```
          $("tr").click(function() {
          var str = this.innerText;
          var i = str.split('').indexOf("   ");
          alert(str.slice(0, i));
        })
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QENwgQ

to get table cell value on click

```
 $("td").click(function(){
  alert(this.innerText);
  })
```

codepen URL for reference- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jrqEBz

Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: A. the question is asking for the *name* to be displayed when the *row* is clicked, not for the contents of the clicked td to be displayed, and B. Your demo doesn't work (DOM elements don't have a `.slice()` method).

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with your code:

1. Your selector `'#test tr #name'` says to select all elements with `id="name"` that are *descendants* of tr elements, but it is actually your tr elements that all have that id. (And speaking of them *all* having that same id, duplicate ids is invalid HTML.)
2. Calling `.click()` binds a click handler to elements that exist *at that moment*. Which means that when your table changes due to an Ajax call your click handler would not work for the newly loaded/created elements even  if you fixed the selector.

The solution to both problems is to use a *delegated* event handler, which you bind to the table element's parent (or to the nearest ancestor element that does not get overwritten by the Ajax call):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#parentElementIdHere").on("click", "#test tr", function(e) {
    var name = $(this).find("td").first().text();
    alert(name);
  });
});
```

When a click occurs on any descendant element of the parent element, jQuery will check if the specific clicked element matches the selector that is the second argument to [the `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and if so it will call your function with `this` set to the matching element. Because the matching element is a tr element, you would then use `.find("td").first()` to get that row's name td.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/269Lt9hm/

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but It seems that it still doesnt work on my side. I have updated my code after seeing yours, please have a look again, is there something i am missing out?

Comment: You said the table gets updated via Ajax - how exactly do you display it? Can you show that JS? Perhaps I didn't explain it very well, but the parent element I was talking about needs to be some ancestor element that is *not* updated by the Ajax, the element into which the Ajax code loads the table. (The change you've added to the code in the question doesn't work because you added a parent element in your Ajax response - I had it like that in my demo because I couldn't call PHP from the demo, so I just kind of simulated it by adding individual rows dynamically.)

Comment: Hmm, maybe i can send you the both of the php files through email if you dont mind? Its kinda hard to keep editing the codes here haha. At the same time it could be because of some other codes which doesnt allow it to run